# Redirigir a index.php todas las pàginas con extension o inexistentes sin modificar URL desde .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Hasta ahora con este código, cuando se intenta acceder a `/foo/bar.php` la pàgina se redirige a 404

```
RewriteEngine on 
# Rewrite /foo/bar to /foo/bar.php
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# Return 404 if original request is /foo/bar.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

Mi intención es que se redirija al `index.php` sin que la url cambie, es decir, que cuando alguien acceda a `/foo/bar.php` simplemente se muestre la pàgina de inicio.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

---

### EDITO para añadir más datos.

Yo ahora mismo tengo esto en mi archivo .htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# redirige xxxx.org/sermons/ a xxxx.org/sermons.php
RewriteRule  ^sermons/?$  sermons.php
# redirige xxxx.org/sermon/14/abc a xxxx.org/sermons.php?id=14&nom=abc
RewriteRule  ^sermon/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ sermons.php?id=$1&nom=$2  

# Redirige cualquer extension .php a error 404
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule . / [L,R=404]

# Indica que el documento de error es /index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

**Y esto és lo que sucede:**

0 `xxxx.og/asd` → Muestra: *File not found.* **ERROR**
1 `xxxx.org/asd/asd*`→ Abre `index.php` *y no modifica URL - OK*
2 `xxxx.org/sermons` → Abre `sermons.php` *y no modifica URL - OK*
3 `xxxx.org/sermons/` → Abre `sermons.php` *y no modifica URL - OK*
4 `xxxx.org/sermons.php` → Abre `index.php` y modifica la url a `xxxx.org` **ERROR**
5 `xxxx.org/sermons.php/` → Abre `sermons.php` *y no modifica URL* **ERROR**
6 `xxxx.org/sermons.php/asd*` → Abre `sermons.php` *y no modifica URL* **ERROR**
7 `xxxx.org/sermons/asd` → Abre `index.php` y modifica URL a `xxxx.org` **ERROR**
8 `xxxx.org/sermons/asd/asd*` → Abre `index.php` *y no modifica URL - OK*
9 `xxxx.org/sermon` → Abre `index.php` y modifica URL **ERROR**
10 `xxxx.org/sermon/asd` → Abre `index.php` *y no modifica URL - OK*
11 `xxxx.org/sermon/asd/asd` → Abre `sermons.php` *y no modifica URL - OK*
12 `xxxx.org/sermon/asd/asd/asd*` → Abre `index.php` y modifica URL **ERROR**

NOTA: `*` és igual a: `/asd/asd/asd/asd/etc....`

**Los ERRORES que necesito solucionar son los sigüientes:**
0 Deberá abrir `index.php`
4 No debería modificar la URL
5 Debería abrir `index.php`
6 Debería abrir `index.php`
7 No debería modificar la URL
9 No debería modificar la URL
12 No debería modificar la URL

Gracias por las respuestas.

Comment: No queda claro cuándo debería redirigir al index. ¿Con cualquier URL terminada en `.php`?  Y ¿debería devolver el 404 junto al contenido del index, o debería dar un 200?

Comment: Debería redirigir a `index.php` siempre que:
1 - La pàgina o dirección no exista  
2 - se escriba .php  
Ejemplos: `xxxx.org/abc`, `xxxx.org/sermon/abc`, etc...

Comment: entonces es 1 **o** 2? Y el cliente debería recibir un 404 aparte de que se le muestre el index.php?

Comment: realmente no es necesario el 404 solo necesito que me redirija siempre al `index.php`  
PD he modificado la pregunta para dar muchos más datos y ser mas preciso, gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ya he encontrado la solución:

Lo primero que debía hacer era borrar todos lo cookies del navegador.

lo segundo que he hecho ha sido borrar todo el .htaccess y reescribirlo así:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# redirige xxxx.org/sermon/14/abc a xxxx.org/sermons.php?id=14&nom=abc
RewriteRule  ^sermon/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ sermons.php?id=$1&nom=$2 [L]

# Redirige De /foo/bar o de /foo/bar/ a /foo/bar.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC] [L]

# Reenvia a inicio si se ha solicitado /foo/bar.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule . / [P,L] # La bandera [p] hace que la URL no es modifique

# Envia todos los errores 404 a index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Espero que pueda servirle a alguien y gracias Mariano y Christopher Villa por vuestra ayuda

Answer (score 0):

La forma facil de resolver esto me parece que es escribir lo siguiente en .htaccess :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Esta linea dejara la url igual pero mostrara el contenido de index.php .

Aunque no se si es la correcta, ¿te funciono?, ¿qué opina el resto?

Comment: gracias, es justamente lo que hago, pero nada me funciona completamente, he editado la pregunta añadiendo muchos mas datos y siendo mucho más preciso, haber si podeis ayudarme