# HTACCESS - Cargar todas las solicitudes desde un único archivo index.php

Tags: .htaccess

Quiero que **todas las solicitudes** a páginas de mi dominio *(ejemplo.com/, ejemplo.com/contacto, etc)* se carguen desde un único archivo.

Es decir, escribiendo cualquier url debería cargar el contenido del archivo `index.php` (**Manteniendo la URL intacta**).

He encontrado [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/145996/redirigir-a-index-php-todas-las-p%C3%A0ginas-con-extension-o-inexistentes-sin-modific), pero no tiene ninguna respuesta que sirva para todos.

Mi objetivo con esto es crear un sistema de rutas, donde el archivo index.php podrá averiguar a qué página o artículo estoy tratando de entrar, y cargarla.
WordPress e incluso este sitio web usa algo similar, dado que no tiene un archivo por cada pregunta, sino que lee la URL y lo busca en la base de datos.

Comment: estás usando apache y quieres que sólo en tu **máquina local** al ingresar en algo.com, otro.com, loquesea.com te redireccione a tu index.php?

Comment: Sí uso apache, pero lo que quiero no es redirigir, sino que todo cargue desde un solo archivo (index.php) sin modificar la URL. Esto me dará posibilidad de crear un sistema de rutas igual que el de Laravel y otros para poder crear por ejemplo artículos con la siguiente URL: ejemplo.com/articulo/ejemplo, sin necesidad de crear un archivo por artículo o usar parámetros (igual que como lo hace WordPress e incluso este mismo sitio)

Comment: ¿Buscas algo como esto? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694118/rerouting-all-php-requests-through-index-php

Comment: @Pavel Sí, buscaba exáctamente eso. Lo probaré, muchas gracias.